# Scheduler - C# App - Batch - FTP - Works Manually But Not In Schedulers

Tags: c#, batch-file, ftp, task, scheduler

I have a C# app which executes a batch script, which writes ftp commands to a text file and then executes the text file.  It works when executed manually, but not when executed from schedulers such as Windows Task Scheduler (not the one I'll ultimately be using but am using for debugging purposes).

Specifically, when run from the scheduler, the script executes, but the parameters don't get passed, and the ftp script file is not overwritten before it is called, so it only executes whatever script was left from the previous job.  It does, however, overwrite the .txt reports that record the ftp session, as intended.  Again, when run manually, it all works.

Security policies prevent much tinkering with permissions, but I gave the job account full permissions on all affected folders, and added "log on as batch file" rights to the job account.  No parameters need to be passed to the C# application.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

C# Code:

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo(scriptFile, paramList);
psi.UseShellExecute = false;
psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
Process p = Process.Start(psi);
//etc...
```

Batch Script:

```
Set DIR=%~1
Set SUBDIR=%~2
Set SWITCH=%~3

cd "%DIR%Scripts\

ECHO USER user>FtpScript.txt
ECHO pass>>FtpScript.txt
ECHO lcd "%DIR%FilesToFtp\%SUBDIR%\%SWITCH%">>FtpScript.txt
ECHO lcd "%DIR%FilesToFtp\%SUBDIR%\%SWITCH%"\>>FtpScript.txt

IF "%SWITCH%"=="ONE" ECHO QUOTE SITE LRECL=100 RECFM=FB>>FtpScript.txt
IF "%SWITCH%"=="TWO" ECHO QUOTE SITE LRECL=200 RECFM=FB>>FtpScript.txt
IF "%SWITCH%"=="THREE" ECHO QUOTE SITE LRECL=300 RECFM=FB>>FtpScript.txt

ECHO MPUT "*.*">>FtpScript.txt
ECHO(>>FtpScript.txt

REM other commands, etc...

FTP -d -n -s:"%DIR%Scripts\FtpScript.txt" server > "%FPATH%Reports\%SUBDIR%_%SWITCH%_log.txt"

EXIT 0
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you collect a batch file output, so that you can check it for any error message? Why don't you create the ftp script from your C# code tou have better error control? (you would get an exception if anything goes wrong when writing to the `FtpScript.txt`.

Comment: I ended up removing the ftp script logic to the C# code, and that resolved the issue.  I will probably be forever haunted by the mystery of the scheduled batch file, but thank you @MartinPrikryl.